# powershell to disable community template for the sub site in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

I have requirement in which, if a user creates a sub-site in a sitecollection then community template feature should not be available to him or he should not be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Site Settings** --> **Page layouts and site templates** (under Look and Feel)

In Subsite Templates section , select **Subsites can only use the following site templates**:

Add your templates and click **OK**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but those site collection have already been created and also there are many site collection

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2013, we can use the PowerShell below to achieve it.

```
$siteCollectionUrl="http://sp2013/sites/team"
$templateNamesToRemove = "COMMUNITY#0","COMMUNITYPORTAL#0"

Start-SPAssignment -Global
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteCollectionUrl

# get the existing web templates from the site that will be filtered down 
# 1033 is the locale id for English US (en-us), be sure to change to your locale 
$existingWebTemplates = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) 
$newWebTemplates = New-Object "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebTemplate]"

# filter existing web templates and only keep if in the list of template names to keep 
$newWebTemplates = $existingWebTemplates | Where-Object {$_.name -notin $templateNamesToRemove} 
$web.SetAvailableWebTemplates($newWebTemplates, 1033) 
$web.Update() 

Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```